# bash: check if two variables both do or do not exist (aka comparing results of comparisons)

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that sometimes will use environment variables `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`.  The bash script can only operate correctly if either both variables exist or neither exist.  In case there's a technical difference, it makes no difference

This works, but there has to be a better way:

```
if [[ -z "${GIT_DIR}" ]]; then
   _GIT_DIR_EXISTS=0
else
   _GIT_DIR_EXISTS=1
fi 
if [[ -z "${GIT_WORK_TREE}" ]]; then
   _GIT_WORK_TREE_EXISTS=0
else
   _GIT_WORK_TREE_EXISTS=1
fi 
if [[ "${_GIT_DIR_EXISTS}" -ne "${_GIT_WORK_TREE_EXISTS}" ]]; then
   echo "GIT_DIR is ${GIT_DIR}"
   echo "GIT_WORK_TREE is ${GIT_WORK_TREE}"
   echo "Both or none must exist"
   exit 1
fi
```

I tried:

```
if [[ (-z "${GIT_DIR}") -ne (-z "${GIT_WORK_TREE}") ]]; then
```

But that gives this error:

```
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near '-ne'
```

I then resorted to trying semi-random things, with varying errors:

```
if [[ -z "${GIT_DIR}" -ne -z "${GIT_WORK_TREE}" ]]; then
if [[ [-z "${GIT_DIR}"] -ne [-z "${GIT_WORK_TREE}"] ]]; then
if [[ [[-z "${GIT_DIR}"]] -ne [[-z "${GIT_WORK_TREE}"]] ]]; then
if [[ -z "${GIT_DIR}" ]] ^ [[ -z "${GIT_WORK_TREE}" ]]; then
if { [[ -z "${GIT_DIR}" ]] } -ne { [[ -z "${GIT_WORK_TREE}" ]] }; then
if [[ (( -z "${GIT_DIR}" )) -ne (( -z "${GIT_WORK_TREE}" )) ]]; then
```

I tried:

```
if [[ $(test -z "${GIT_DIR}") -ne $(test -z "${GIT_WORK_TREE}") ]]; then
```

But realized that doesn't work because <s>it's a sub-process, and they'd need to be exported.</s> as Socowl comments, this compares the outputs of the `test` commands which output nothing, not their exit statuses.

I apologize if this is a duplicate.  I've searched here and google for a while, and must not be using the right terminology.

Comment: `that doesn't work because it's a sub-process, and they'd need to be exported.` The real reason why `$(test ...) -ne $(test ...)` does not work is because you compare the outputs of `test` instead of their exit statuses. However, `test` does not output anything, so the command is equivalent to `'' -ne ''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
if [[ "${GIT_DIR:+set}" != "${GIT_WORK_TREE:+set}" ]]; then
   echo "GIT_DIR is '${GIT_DIR}'"
   echo "GIT_WORK_TREE is '${GIT_WORK_TREE}'"
   echo "Both or none must exist"
   exit 1
fi
```

Explanation: `${var:+value}` is a variant of parameter expansion that gives "value" if `var` is set to a nonempty string, or the empty string if `var` is unset or empty. So if both vars are unset/empty, it becomes `if [[ "" != "" ]]; then`, and if they're both set it becomes `if [[ "set" != "set" ]]; then` etc.

BTW, if you want to test whether the variables are set at all (even if to the empty string), use `${var+value}` (note the lack of colon). The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) lists the `:+` version, but not the `+` version.